# No response or output running aws command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There's a task I need to complete:

1. list out all the count of AWS Network Interface - which I ran this

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=attachment.status,Values=attached --query 'length(NetworkInterfaces)'
```

But it returns blank, nothing shows
[enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRIb5.png

Would anyone know any troubleshooting steps I can take to figure out why its showing blank?

Ideally, I need to get a count and list of all network interfaces that are not in used, so I can remove them.

Comment: Are you sure you are querying the correct AWS region? What happens when you remove the `--query` parameter so you can see all the data coming back?

Comment: So I added --debug, it seems like I'm having issues with cert due to company proxy vpn. When I run "aws sts get-caller-identity" works... theres output... once I do something in an specific service... it doesnt output... debug shows cert errors.

Comment: ANSWER: If you're under company VPN/proxy/firewall you need to make sure you add PEM cert to your aws folder and then bundle your aws configure with it

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Network Interfaces are a regional resource. Use `aws configure` to check which region you are querying, or specify the `--region <aws_region>` flag in your command.

```bash
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region us-east-1
```